# Geocoder / Fly Map Problem

Tags: geocoding, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm a little stumped with this issue that I'm having.. I have a large zip code map (the whole U.S.) with a Geocoder. When I do a search for a particular zip code, and press enter or select it, the map is programmatically clicked on the longitude/latitude of the resulting zip code area. This works initially. The map flies down to the particular zip code, and highlights (just like it's supposed to do upon click). If the user enters a different zip code that is within the viewport, it will activate again (like it's supposed to).. HOWEVER, if the user selects a zip code OUTSIDE the view port, the view port "flies" over to the new place but does not fire the click event, and so therefore, nothing is selected.

I have a JS Fiddle documenting the behavior.

https://jsfiddle.net/wbeelergofish/t5heL2vz/

EDIT: I'm not sure that the 'fire' event is fired or not, but it does not work like it's supposed when the fly action is finished taking place outside the current view port.